# Maximum of register/memory operands

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I'd like to figure out the maximal possible number of both explicit and implicit register operands (incl. segment, `eflags`) of any IA32 / AMD64 instruction that may occur in the *user-mode code* (i.e. lets ignore `iret` etc). The same - for memory operands.
I couldn't find explicit numbers in the Intel specs, but it looks like they are as follows:

IA32 registers: 8 (`pusha`, `popa`).

IA32 memory: 2 (`cmps`, `movs`, etc).

AMD64 registers: 6 (`repe movs`, etc).

AMD64 memory: same as for IA32.

Is the above correct or I missed something?

Comment: Saving the "floating point/MMX/SSE/...  context" hits a lot of implicit registers, and you can do that in user mode.  Is that out of scope for your question?  What do you really want to know?

Comment: @Ira Baxter You're right, lets ignore fp/mmx - I'm interested in gpr/segment only. I'm instrumenting a user-mode code, and there are places where I have to use fixed buffers, that's where the question comes from.

Comment: `PUSHA` used 9 registers (AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, BP, SP, SS). Also `IRET` isn't a privileged instruction, it can be used in user mode code (and in this case uses SS, SP, FLAGS, CS, IP). So it's not entirely clear what you're include and excluding in your counting here. Also arguably an instruction like `PUSHA` has 8 implicit memory operands.

Comment: ia32 cmpxchg8 reg, sib  touches flags, reg and EAX (I thnk), plus the base and index registers.   Guess that's only 5.

Comment: `loadall` instruction :)

Comment: @Ross Ridge I never stated `pusha` has 8 implicit memory operands, I wrote it has 8 implicit *register* ops (this is because I missed SS selector). `IRET` in the user mode doesn't seem to break the record of `pusha` anyway. So is 9 the maximum for registers?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff oh... is it really used anywhere nowadays?

Comment: You've completely misunderstood my comment.

Comment: @Ross Ridge right, sorry. I tested `pusha` with DynamoRIO, and it treats this instruction as having a single memory operand, which makes sense as it writes to a contiguous memory block.

Comment: Either way of looking at it can make sense depending on what you're trying to do. That's the problem here, it's hard to come up a definitive answer because it's not clear what exactly you're counting. How many memory operands does `CALL FWORD PTR[EAX]` have? Two, three or four are all possible answers given your disclosed criteria. (The explicit memory operand, the stack, the GDT or LDT, and the address of called function). What about a software interrupt like `INT 80h`? If that invokes a task gate, it ends up using pretty much every register you haven't excluded.

Comment: Can you describe the programming problem you're having? That may help people understand the context of the question. Right now it is kind foo a theoretical question. Are you writing a CPU emulator?

Comment: Even if you exclude context-saving instructions, vector `vzeroall` / `vzeroupper` touch a lot of registers.  (16 in 64bit mode, or 32 with AVX-512 in 64bit mode.)  Other than that, though, I'm pretty sure even the most complex vector instructions don't touch as many registers as `pusha`.